# Jquery Mobile Sliders: How to store JQM Slider values site-wide, then recall those values on a new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, range

I need to add up all of my JQM slider values, site-wide. I have 5 pages with 4 sliders on each. I am categorizing the values via 5 different classes. I want to add up and then average all of the values in each given class (.ex, .ag, .co, .ne, and op) on the final page. Is there an easy way of doing this?

The code below correctly categorizes and totals the values for one page. All five pages are the same, but with different questions. I would love any help I can get. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="mysliders">
            <label for="Slider17">Is a Trendsetter:</label>
            <input class="op" type="range" name="Slider17" id="Slider17" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider18">Handles Stress Well:</label>
            <input class="ne" type="range" name="Slider18" id="Slider18" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider19">Prefers an Active Lifestyle:</label>
            <input class="ex" type="range" name="Slider19" id="Slider19" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider20">Is Punctual:</label>
            <input class="co" type="range" name="Slider20" id="Slider20" min="1" max="5" value="3" />

        </div>
        <hr />
        <p>Extraversion: <strong id="total"></strong></p>
        <p>Agreeableness: <strong id="total2"></strong></p>
        <p>Conscientiousness: <strong id="total3"></strong></p>
        <p>Neuroticism: <strong id="total4"></strong></p>
        <p>Openess: <strong id="total5"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Footer</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".ex").on("change", function () {
        addAll();
    });
    addAll();
});
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".ag").on("change", function () {
        addAll2();
    });
    addAll2();
});
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".co").on("change", function () {
        addAll3();
    });
        addAll3();
});
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".ne").on("change", function () {
        addAll4();
    });
    addAll4();
});
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".op").on("change", function () {
        addAll5();
    });
    addAll5();
});


function addAll() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.ex').each(function (){        
        sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
    });
    $('#total').html(sum);
}
function addAll2() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.ag').each(function (){        
        sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
    });
    $('#total2').html(sum);
}
function addAll3() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.co').each(function (){        
        sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
    });
    $('#total3').html(sum);
}
function addAll4() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.ne').each(function (){        
        sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
    });
    $('#total4').html(sum);
}
function addAll5() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.op').each(function (){        
        sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
    });
    $('#total5').html(sum);
}
```

[See Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/TangoHotel355/kmuuhfL8/)

Comment: I created a Demo for you to get selected sliders values and sum them up -- https://jsfiddle.net/tzwsjsru/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

- Save the values in one or multiple cookies
- Save the values in local storage
- Add the values to your links (GET)
- Save the values via ajax on a server

Comment: Hi Joerg, I think that I need to use the last solution that you proposed but I do not know how. I am hazy when it comes to php, especially when it comes to interaction with ajax.  I just began learning about php and mySQL when I originally posted the question. I have been very busy since then, but I am now getting back to it. Do you have any suggestions on how I would go about doing this? I am greatly appreciative for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your code and made it con size including the total logic, both on change of the slider and on initial stage:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmuuhfL8/6/

Javascript code changes:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    printValue();
    $(".slider").on("change", function () {
        printValue();
    });
});

function printValue() {      
    var sumAll = 0;
   $('.slider').each(function( index ) {
     $('#sum' + $(this).attr('id')).html($(this).val());
     sumAll += isNaN($(this).val()) ||$(this).val()=== '' ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val()); 
    });

    $('#sumAllSlider').html(sumAll);
}
```

HTML changes:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Question Page 1</h1> 
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="mysliders">
            <label for="Slider17">Question One:</label>
            <input class="slider" type="range" name="Slider17" id="Slider17" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider18">Question Two:</label>
            <input class="slider" type="range" name="Slider18" id="Slider18" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider19">Question Three:</label>
            <input class="slider" type="range" name="Slider19" id="Slider19" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
            <label for="Slider20">Question Four:</label>
            <input class="slider" type="range" name="Slider20" id="Slider20" min="1" max="5" value="3" />

             <label for="Slider21">Question Five:</label>
            <input class="slider" type="range" name="Slider21" id="Slider21" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
        </div>
    <div id="totals">
        <hr />
        <p>Extraversion: <strong id="sumSlider17"></strong></p>
        <p>Agreeableness: <strong id="sumSlider18"></strong></p>
        <p>Conscientiousness: <strong id="sumSlider19"></strong></p>
        <p>Neuroticism: <strong id="sumSlider20"></strong></p>
        <p>Openess: <strong id="sumSlider21"></strong></p>
         <p>Total: <strong id="sumAllSlider"></strong></p>

     </div>
  </div>   
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1></h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```